# Pushing data to a UICollectionView inside a UIContainerView from a UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, delegates

I currently have a Viewcontroller which does the heavy lifting of retrieving the data. I then need to push this data to my UICollectionView inside of a UIContainerView. I have tried pushing via a segue but I need to keep refreshing the data so I keep getting the error:

```
'There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?'
```

I then went on to investigate delegates and made a protocol to share the data between the two classes, however how can I initiate a a reloadData function from my initial view controller?

[image: First view controller passing data to collection view inside a uicontainer]

I'm still very new to delegates but I've setup the following:

```
protocol ProductsViewControllerDelegate {
    var catalogue : CatalogueData {get set}
}
```

I then get my first view controller to inherit this delegate and pass data to it. I then created a delegate instance in the collection view and at the segue I set the `collectionview.delegate = self` however how do I refresh the data when I pass new data to it?

**UPDATE**

So I believe my problem is that the data isn't passing in the first place. My setup is as follows: 
View controller:

```
    struct CatalogueData {
        var data : NSArray
        var numberOfRows : Int
        var numberOfColumns : Int
        var tileName : XibNames
    }
    class ProductsViewController:UIViewController, CollectionCatalogueDelegate{
            internal var catalogue: CatalogueData!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                let catdta : CatalogueData = CatalogueData(data: ProductCodes,
                                                               numberOfRows: 2,
                                                               numberOfColumns: 4,
                                                               tileName: XibNames.ProductDisplayTall)
                self.catalogue = catdta

            }


     }
```

The second collection view inside of the container view is setup like so:

```
protocol CollectionCatalogueDelegate {
    var catalogue : CatalogueData! {get set}
}
class CollectionCatalogue: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    @IBOutlet var cv: UICollectionView?
    var delegate : CollectionCatalogueDelegate?{
        didSet{
            cv?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (self.delegate?.catalogue.data.count)!
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        self.cv?.register(UINib(nibName: (self.delegate?.catalogue?.tileName.rawValue)!, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: (self.delegate?.catalogue?.tileName.rawValue)!)

        let c:ProductCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: selectedXib.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ProductCollectionCell
        c.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        c.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        c.layer.cornerRadius = 3

        let mng = (self.delegate?.catalogue?.data)![indexPath.row] as? NSManagedObject

      '...........DO STUFF WITH DATA HERE ETC
      }

}
```

And dependant on other actions I will then want to update the 'catalogue' in the first view controller and it display the results on the collection view.

Comment: did you try `catalogue {didSet {}}`. does your data pass but not refreshed? I got it right?

Comment: no I haven't. I'll have a read up on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html and I'll report back

Comment: `didSet` is getting called when this property did set (changed), so you can refresh your views. if no problems are faced while passing data, just add this and everything would be ok.